# JavaScript won't work on my rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a problem with running js/jquery in my rails app.
I have Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.3 installed.

I have two js files in /app/assets/javascripts:

```
application.js
main.js
```

I created this main.js. In it there is this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('Hello world!');
});
```

my application.js has the following:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require main.js
```

When I open my app, no alert message pops up!

Opening the source code, i see all the js files in place:

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/main.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What I am doing wrong???

Comment: What do you see if you open the `/assets/main.js?body=1` path in your browser (e.g. http://localhost:3000/assets/main.js?body=1)

Comment: i see the code that is supposed to be in there: $( document ).ready( function() 
{
 alert( "Hello world!" ) ;
});

Comment: have you checked any console output - press f12 in Chrome or IE...

Comment: just checked the console output, no javascript error or warning...

Comment: Would you place a console.log('something') statement outside of the jQuery ready function, in main.js and let us know if it outputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, I made a mistake.
I gave false information about the name of my js file for abstracting purposes.
The originial name of my was advert.js and for whatever reason it does not get executed as js.
I remembered that I used advert.css in this project and it was also not recognized by rails as css, even if it was loaded. I renamed that advert.css to popup.css and it worked, so it did now with my advert.js. Renamed it to popup.js and it works!

Answer (score 1):

```
//= require_tree .
```

should be the last line always in your application.js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('Hello world!');
})
```

doesn't need the last semicolon, also

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery.js** and **jquery_ujs.js** are not in your assets folder according to your post

Comment: right, but i can access them via http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.js?body=1 and http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1.
I guess the jquery-rails gem handles this

Answer (score 0):

Try to write `alert($);` or `console.log($);` on the top of *main.js*.

Is `$` undefined?